# Создание 3D Flash игры

Tags: android, flash, разработка-игр, actionscript

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу создать игру наподобие TempleRun, также для мобильных телефонов, Android в основном.
[image]
Так вот, есть ли какие нибудь предположения, как эта игра создавалась?
В написании игр я новичок и было бы интересно узнать процесс создания 3D игр на подобий этой + знания каких языков программирования нужны?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это примитивный OpenGl ES 2.0(или 1.0) рендер.  Тут вода даже просто нарисованная статичная текстура. Вся анимация бега человечка и монстров - keyframe экспортированный из 3DSMax. Насколько мне известно эту игру делало [3 человека](http://www.imangistudios.com/about.html). У меня есть небольшой опыт в разработке игр и по моим оценкам такую игрушку с нуля(самописный движок) можно получить за 4-6 месяцев ленивой разработки командой из 3 человек(если не считать рекламу, издание, портирование перевод на разные языки, интернет сайты и.т.д.). Геймдизайнер +Хороший программист + 3D моделлер/художник. Основная причина успеха этой игры в весьма оригинальном, продуманном геймплее и бесплатности. Графика здесь на уровне второсортных 3D шутеров 1996 года выпуска. А вообще разработка игр очень серьезный процесс. Нельзя просто выучить язык программирования и написать на нем игру. По меньшей мере кроме кода Вам потребуется еще увесистая пачка дизайн документов с ее подробным описанием и инструкциями для различных участников проекта. Если собрались разрабатывать игру пишите сначала дизайн документы, чтобы другие люди могли разобраться в проекте и только потом на их основании код.

Comment: не могли бы вы конкретно написать, что нужно для разработки игры? 
дизайнер есть, я хочу стать тем самым хорошим программистом. Что для этого требуется?

Comment: @Wars Умение программировать и знание платформы, под которую собрался писать, не? :)

Comment: первое есть, под вторым подразумевается Flash/AS3 или же Android?

Comment: @Wars

- Вы предлагаете мне выбрать за вас платформу для вашей будушей игры? :) `Flash` - под веб, `Android` - как ни странно, под `Android.` На флеше под `Android` не пишут, обратное, естественно, тоже верно.

- Для разработки под `Android` желательно понимание принципов трехмерной графики и того, как работают современные `3d` движки. Правда, казуалку можно сделать и на `canvas'e` - было бы желание и энтузиазм.

Comment: @Wars

- И да, забудьте про *"превращение flash в apk".* Написать хорошую флеш-игру - **сложно, но можно.** Написать хорошую флеш-игру так, чтобы в нее было круто и интересно играть под `Android` без полноценного порта, учитывающего особенности `Android` - **невозможно.**

Comment: просто видел курс на рутрекере от lynda.com где он превращает веб-игру в полноценное Android приложение. Вот и решил, что можно.

Comment: @Wars 

- Ну я тоже видел парочку видео, где Василий Сергеевич Пупкин программирует на `Haskell'e`.

- Не знаю, мое личное мнение, что `AIR` для `Android` не подходит для промышленной разработки. Возможно, кто-нибудь сможет меня переубедить.

Comment: 1) Страсть к играм. 2) Университетский курс простой математики(линейная алгебра, матанализ, кватернионы, численные методы и выч. мат) 3) Физика(Тут уровень зависит от того что вам нужно. Если temple run то можно обойтись и без нее. А так в основном оптика(свет, тени спецэффекты), гидродинамика(вода и остальные внутриигровые жидкости), механика Лагранжа(гравитация, взаимодействие между объектами) и.т.д) 4) Заведомо хорошее знание платформы на которой вы решили работать и умение тотально оптимизировать код.

Comment: Также согласен с Котик_хочет кушать. Если хотите сделать 3D игру для мобильных платформ вообще забудьте про flash навсегда. По поводу шаблонов проектирования, парадигм ООП и обобщенного программирования, то при построении 3D движков все это нужно в лучшем случае для того чтобы сделать код понятнее другим программистам и организовать нормальный интерфейс между движком и программами в которых делалась графика. Вся библиотека OpenGL например состоит просто из полсотни статичных функций. Хороший пример отсутствия ООП исходники Quake3. http://www.shacknews.com/file/7443/quake-3-132-source-code

Comment: Хороший пример отсутствия ООП в играх - исходники Quake3. http://www.shacknews.com/file/7443/quake-3-132-source-code
Только typedef, только хардкор.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если на Flash писать, то нужно знание Ation script. Но Flash это вроде как спорная технология сейчас, особенно с появлением HTML5.
Если на Android'ы, то наверняка Java либо C++. Особой разницы нет, на чем писать (вы же новичок), но C++ малость пошустрее будет да ресурсы экономит (Performance per $ выше, чем я Явы).
Знать нужно многое - ООП, сам язык, шаблоны проектирования наверняка так же желательны будут, нужны так же будут (наверняка) основы тригонометрии и линейная алгебра, т.к. вся трехмерная графика, собственно, основана на вычислениях, связанных с поворотами, переносами масштабированием плоскостей (треугольников) в пространстве, основываясь на их координатах (вычисления с матрицами), а также операций с векторами (нахождение векторного произведения, и т.д.)
Я не ахти какой мастер в написании 3D игр, но я бы Вам посоветовал начать изучать ООП+язык+в связке с каким-нибудь 3D движком на Android'e (ну либо же изучать Open GL).
Короче, думаю, уже ближайшие месяца три Вам точно будет чем заняться =)

Comment: ООП знаю, а можно поконкретнее про шаблоны проектирования, типа MVC? + хочу писать игры именно на Flash и AS3, так как слышал, что flash игру можно будет превратить в apk файл, большинство именно так и делают игры, а насчет java и c++, то нет особого желания писать нативные приложения :) 
спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не ну шаблоны вообще не обязательны грубо говоря. В принципе и без ООП можно даже обойтись. Ну делайте тогда на Flash, просто поймите одну вещь, Flash\AS это интерпретируемые языки, и если игра потребует слишком много вычислений, ресурсов мобильной платформы Вам может просто не хватить.